# Rich HTML Annotations in HighCharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, annotations

Is it possible to add HTML elements in Highcharts annotations? Specially I'm looking for hyperlinks in highcharts annotations. Is there any demo/example?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. All you need is to set the `annotations.labels.useHTML` to true.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ycz7j25t/

```
annotations: [{
    labels: [{
        point: 'min',
        text: "<a href='https://www.highcharts.com/'>test</a>",
                    useHTML: true,
        backgroundColor: 'white'
    }]
}]
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/annotations.labels.useHTML

Comment: Thanks a lot Sebastian!